# Testing input fields not available for web service in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I have a web service that I am trying to test in Visual Web Developer Express Edition (Service Pack 1).  I am working with two different websites on two different branches from an SVN repository but largely the same code.  The web services are the same code but there are some code differences for other features.

My problem is that when going to the web service specification page in debug mode (i.e. MyWebService.asmx) there should be text fields for inputting parameters for that web service.  On one of these web sites the fields are available.  On another they are not available.  I don't understand why/how there should be any differences between the two setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the fields when HTTP POST is available as a submission option, if you have complex types in your submission parameters then HTTP POST may not be able to handle them and as such won't be enabled... then the fields won't be present on the helper page.

Comment: Complex types shouldn't be an issue here.  A website on one of my development branches works fine yet another doesn't.  They are the exact same code for the web service.  There should be some other factors to check.

Comment: Turns out this was actually an issue where my web service was binding to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost preventing the input fields from showing up for one of my development branches.  A restart of the computer seemed to be a suggested solution to this issue around the internet which is what I did and it resolved the issue.

Your answer however Lazarus is correct as I have discovered while researching this issue around the net